# How to resolve localhost in a nodejs app?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, dns

I have a nodejs express server running no my ubuntu vm which is running inside a windows laptop. I am trying to make a request to another nodejs app, also on express running in the same vm.

I was getting an error saying `Your requested host 'localhost' could not be resolved`

After searching a bit on google and playing around with DNS settings which did not work, I just replaced `localhost` with `127.0.0.1` on my calling express app.

This is now not failing with the error but responding with a link to microsoft iis server page.

I'm not sure how to solve this? 
Is changing the DNS only way to go?

EDIT:

nodejs app is running on 3000(Serving some jsons), verified from browser.
But through `curl` I'm getting a redirect response:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>Redirection</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY><H1>Redirect</H1></BODY>
```

In node REPL, I' getting a microsoft IIS page as response:

```
request('http://127.0.0.1:3000/abc', function(error, response, body) { console.log(response);});

body: '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">\r\n' +
'<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">\r\n' +
'<head>\r\n' +
'<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />\r\n' +
'<title>IIS Windows</title>\r\n' +
'<style type="text/css">\r\n' +
'<!--\r\n' +
'body {\r\n' +
'\tcolor:#000000;\r\n' +
'\tbackground-color:#0072C6;\r\n' +
'\tmargin:0;\r\n' +
'}\r\n' +
'\r\n' +
'#container {\r\n' +
'\tmargin-left:auto;\r\n' +
'\tmargin-right:auto;\r\n' +
'\ttext-align:center;\r\n' +
'\t}\r\n' +
'\r\n' +
'a img {\r\n' +
'\tborder:none;\r\n' +
'}\r\n' +
'\r\n' +
'-->\r\n' +
'</style>\r\n' +
'</head>\r\n' +
'<body>\r\n' +
'<div id="container">\r\n' +
'<a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=66138&amp;clcid=0x409"><img src="iisstart.png" alt="IIS" width="960" height="600" /></a>\r\n' +
'</div>\r\n' +
'</body>\r\n' +
'</html>'
```

Comment: The VM and the host operating systems will be on *different IP addresses*, they won't both respond to localhost or a loopback address (the 127.0.0.0/8 IP range).

Comment: @VLAZ Sorry I couldn't understand. Both my nodejs apps are running in the same ubuntu VM and I'm able to access them from a browser using 127.0.0.1

Comment: Ah, sorry - I thought you had one app within the VM, another outside of it. My bad. I'm not really sure why you have problems within the same machine, then - the two *should* be visible through locahost or 127.0.0.1. Especially if you can access them through the browser. Just to verify - are you calling the correct port, e.g., `localhost:8080` or whatever? Also, are you making the correct type of request - the browser would be making a GET, perhaps the app is only responding to POST or something? You can test the API using `wget` or `curl` from the command line to be extra sure it works.

Comment: @VLAZ I've edited the question for clarity.

Comment: If the code is calling `dns.resolve()`, it's sending an actual DNS request to some DNS server (on ubuntu that's likely to be locally running `dnsmasq`?) and you need that server to respond to `localhost`.  If the code uses `dns.lookup()`, you need to ensure it appears in `/etc/hosts`.  See https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_implementation_considerations